# PIP install gives "subprocess-exited-with-error"

Tags: python, pip, langchain, py-langchain

I have been facing this issue while installing langchain using pip, although the pip version i used before was older but even after updating the pip version ,  i'm not able to make progress and would love to hear your solution for the same

```
pip install langchain
Collecting langchain
  Using cached langchain-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (797 kB)
Collecting langsmith<0.1.0,>=0.0.77
  Using cached langsmith-0.0.80-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting dataclasses-json<0.7,>=0.5.7
  Using cached dataclasses_json-0.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting numpy<2,>=1
  Downloading numpy-1.26.3.tar.gz (15.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 15.7/15.7 MB 3.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
        Using cached ninja-1.11.1.1.tar.gz (132 kB)
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
     
        Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1
     
        [13 lines of output]
        C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f5ulx9yv\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:308: UserWarning: git archive did not support describe output
          warnings.warn("git archive did not support describe output")
        C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f5ulx9yv\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_scm\git.py:327: UserWarning: unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)
          warnings.warn("unprocessed git archival found (no export subst applied)")
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f5ulx9yv\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
            cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f5ulx9yv\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__    
            self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
          File "C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-f5ulx9yv\overlay\lib\python3.10\site-packages\skbuild\cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
            raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
     
        Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
        [end of output]
     
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
      Failed to build ninja
      ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
     
      [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 23.3.2
      [notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I've tried updating pip, but i'm not able to resolve this

Comment: It looks that you need `cmake` to be installed.